# Missing short urls created via Campaign URL Builder in goo.gl dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, utm, google-url-shortener, goo.gl, google-analytics-campaign-builder

If you create short URL directly via goo.gl , you can track all links at one place in goo.gl dashboard.

However goo.gl do not shows short url created via  Campaign URL builder.
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

In above builder there is option to make URL short, which generates goo.gl short url with UTM tracking

But links created via it do not show up in goo.gl dashboard.

Any way to track this URLs at one place?

Answer (score 0):

Google URL shortener only creates stats for URls that were created when you were logged into your Google account.   When some one clicks on a shortenered link they are sent to the goo.gl website where the hit is recorded and the url is parsed back to the original url and the are forwarded to the site in question.

Google Analytics is not going to track a hit to goo.gl its going to track a hit to the original url.  probably with a referral from goo.gl but I am not 100% sure about that one.

The Google Analytics campaign builder has nothing to do with google url shortner so its not going to save your links there either.

Comment: I think, I didn't able to explain the question properly.... Here is rephrase version,
When you create short urls directly via "goo.gl" , you can see all your short yours at one place... whereas if you create it via "Campaign builder" then it do not appear on goo.gl dashboard

Comment: Google Analytics Campaign builder does not save your campaigns its just a tool to help you create them.    It has nothing to do with Google URL shortener and is not going to save the links there.

Comment: Oh, may be they should add this feature...bcoz it is hard to track those links...any work around this problem?